# Passing a C# String array to C++

Tags: c#, c++, .net

I have a string array in C# for example:

```
string[] level = {"results","isPA"}
```

Now I need to pass this array to a C++ Function.

The wrapper looks like this:

```
[DllImport("File.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.StdCall, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)

public static extern long SetJsonString(string[] Level, string Entry, string Item);
```

The C++ function then gets called using:

```
long SetJsonString(char** Level, char* Entry, char* Item)
```

If I know want to access the single elements of the array I only get the first one.
Does anybody have some ideas how to handle the passing?

Comment: Are you asking how to only pass the first character?

Comment: I'm not sure which way the array is being passed.  There are two possibilities 1)  In memory as follows : 'abcd\0efgh\0\0 2) Starting at address 1000 points to the data : 0x00001008, 0x1000000D,abcd\0efgh\0  where 1008 is pointing to abcd\0 and 100D is pointing to efgh\0.  The pointers are 4 bytes with bytes swapped 00008010 (00001008) and 00000D10 (000100D)

Comment: Maybe using SafeArray like suggestion in this [link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189085/Passing-strings-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code) could help

Comment: @John No, I want to acces the whole Strings. In this case _results_ and _isPA_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SafeArray just like [Thinh Tran](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13838011/thinh-tran) suggested did the trick.

The code can be found here: [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1189085/Passing-strings-between-managed-and-unmanaged-code) in the "Passing an Array of Strings" paragraph.